# Merge two array items into one based on common field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following following collection (in Json format) -

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1111),
    "valueArray" : [ 
        {
            "accountNumber" : NumberLong(12345),
            "levels" : [ 
                1, 
                13
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "accountNumber" : NumberLong(67890),
            "levels" : [ 
                2
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(2222),
    "valueArray" : [ 
        {
            "accountNumber" : NumberLong(33333),
            "levels" : [ 
                13, 
                1
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "accountNumber" : NumberLong(33333),
            "levels" : [ 
                8
            ]
        },
        {
            "accountNumber" : NumberLong(44444),
            "levels" : [ 
                5
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice the 2nd document where accountNumber is same (33333). I want to merge these into single entry. The output should look like -

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1111),
    "valueArray" : [ 
        {
            "accountNumber" : NumberLong(12345),
            "levels" : [ 
                1, 
                13
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "accountNumber" : NumberLong(67890),
            "levels" : [ 
                2
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(2222),
    "valueArray" : [ 
        {
            "accountNumber" : NumberLong(33333),
            "levels" : [ 
                13, 
                1,
                8
            ]
        },
        {
            "accountNumber" : NumberLong(44444),
            "levels" : [ 
                5
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried multiple approaches $concatArrays, $setUnion etc but I end getting some or other error. Even if I am able to get some output, it is not in required format.

Can someone please help here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use double [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get single document per `valueArray.accountNumber` and the double [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to aggregate those values, initialy by `accountNumber` and then by `_id`, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$valueArray"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$valueArray.levels"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                _id: "$_id",
                accountNumber: "$valueArray.accountNumber"
            },
            levels: { $push: "$valueArray.levels" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            valueArray: {
                $push: { accountNumber: "$_id.accountNumber", levels: "$levels" }
            }
        }
    }
])
```